# Notation for a proof containing group actions

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, notation, group-actions, sylow-theory

I am writing a proof to Sylow's 2nd Theorem. I have done it using group actions. My tutor told me it would be wise to introduce notation to make it more clear what group action I am talking about. I am unsure on how to do this. Do I just assign letters to each group action?

Comment: This is rather vague. You should probably follow up with your tutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not perfect choice of notation. Look into the lecture notes or ask your tutor/other students.

I like this notation for group actions:
For a left action of $g \in G$ acting on an element $x$ you could write
$$
g \rhd x.
$$

To differentiate between different group actions, you could introduce for example $\rhd_A$ and $\rhd_B$ to make clear which group action you refer to.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful!!